# RecyclerView or LayoutManager footer

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a custom `RecyclerView` and I need to make rows of images that expand/collapse when scrolling. I did everything except the last row won't expand because the scroll has reached it's end and `onScrolled` is not called anymore.

My first workaround was, to make custom `Adapter` and add a footer there, but that is not very efficient for a `CustomRecyclerView`.

I also extended `LinearLayoutManager`, is it possible I could create a footer there or expand the scroll range? I tried overriding the `computeVerticalScrollRange` but it had no effect on the scrolling whatsoever.

I would like to make scroll longer for `expandedHeight - collapsedHeight`

so I was thinking of making this:

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return (super.computeVerticalScrollRange(state) + (maxHeight - minHeight));
}
```

Unfortunately as I said, nothing was changed. This method was overriden in LayoutManager, I also tried to override it in RecycleView but same result.